# Getting value of css padding-left with jquery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem with getting css padding-left value with jQuery, when css is not inline. Problem exists in Internet Explorer only (I tried versions 8 and 9).

I want to print this value out like this:

```
alert($content.css("padding-left"));
```

$content includes a <div> with class, which has (in external css file) defined value "padding-left". If I put same css directive into inline "style" attribute, I get value printed as expected.

One more thing... I inspected style of my div with developer tools and there everything shows correct.

Because of this problem I found out, that jQuery's method outerWidth() does not work correct.

Does anyone have solution, how to get value of "padding-left" from external css? Or is this just bug in jQuery and I have to report it there and wait for fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that if div is not visible yet, jquery cannot get value of "padding-left" directive of external css in Internet Explorer.